# How can I limit access to a particular class to one caller at a time in an ASMX web service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, multithreading, asmx

I have a web service method in which I create a particular type of object, use it for a few seconds, and then dispose it.  Because of problems arising from multiple threads creating and using instances of this class at the same time, I need to restrict the method so that only one caller at a time ever has one of these objects.

To do this, I am creating a private static object:

```
private static object _lock = new object();
```

... and then inside the web service method I do this around the critical code:

```
lock (_lock)
{
    using (DangerousObject dob = new DangerousObject())
    {
        dob.MakeABigMess();
        dob.CleanItUp();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is working, though.  Do I have this right?  Will this code ensure that only one instance of `DangerousObject` is instantiated and in use at a time?  Or does each caller get their own copy of `_lock`, rendering my code here laughable?

**Update:**  from a link in Ben Voigt's answer, I think I need to do this instead:

```
Mutex m = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MyMutex");
m.WaitOne();
try
{
    using (DangerousObject dob = new DangerousObject())
    {
        dob.MakeABigMess();
        dob.CleanItUp();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // what could possibly go wrong?
}
finally
{
    m.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

This should function pretty much the same as my `lock` code, but it will instead use a global object (because of the "Global\" prefix in the mutex' name).  I hope.

Comment: Why isn't it thread-safe? Can you fix it?

Comment: I wish. DangerousObject = Oracle Lite connection. With multiple threads going concurrently we occasionally get the "POL-2000 out of memory" error, which indicates exhausted and/or corrupt memory (the server of course has plenty of overall memory when this happens).

Comment: As soon as this exception appears once, all further attempts to connect to Oracle Lite databases fail with this error. It clears itself after almost exactly 3 hours (or if we reboot).

Comment: Since no one on Earth is using Oracle Lite, I haven't bothered to ask about this here.  I'm asking about this locking code because it didn't fix the problem, so I'm trying to make sure I did it right.

Comment: Is it used by multiple applications?

Comment: Is this in an ASMX web service?

Comment: @John: yes, it is an ASMX web service.

Comment: @Slaks: there are two different client applications (each with multiple instances running) that call the same web method in the same web service, but this method only exists inside the one web service.

Comment: I don't know asp.net, but I'm hoping it doesn't work because "rendering my code here laughable" is such a good turn of a phrase that it would be a shame if it didn't come true.

Comment: @Bert F: I've been kicked in the ass by threading too many times to have any pride in the matter any more. He/she/it who says "I am the master of multithreading" is doomed to saying "but it works on my machine" for the rest of eternity.

Comment: @Aaronaught: check out http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp

Comment: In the text underneath figure 5: "In order to deal with ‘hung requests’ ASP.NET forcefully shuts down the AppDomain after the request timeout period is up even if requests are still pending. So it’s actually possible that two AppDomains exist for the same HttpApplication at a given point in time as the old one’s shutting down and the new one is ramping up."

Comment: The new AppDomain would have a new instance of `_lock`, meaning that the first request to use DangerousObject would be allowed, even though a thread in the old (but still alive) AppDomain is still using it.

Comment: Actually, scratch part of what I said above, I hadn't seen the full context of all the answers and comments; Ben is right, if the resource is *that* sensitive, and you recycle the app pool in ASP.NET, then it's incredibly unlikely but theoretically possible that a new AppDomain has been started while the recycled AppDomain is still trying to unload and play cleanup.  So yeah, if multiple consumers of this resource would be catastrophic, you'll need a global mutex.

Comment: @Bert F: good news! My code is indeed laughable (in that it does not achieve what it's trying to achieve).

Comment: @Aaronaught: I think my lock might have actually made the problem worse, because it would cause multiple requests to wait for the lock to clear. ASP.NET might take this as a sign that it needs to start a new AppDomain.

Comment: @Musi, a mutex is no different in that respect, but the shutdown timeout in ASP.NET only applies to when you've already decided to shut down (or recycle) an app pool/worker process - it's how long ASP.NET is allowed to wait for a "graceful" shutdown before turning it into a "forced" shutdown - so it's really kind of a moot point if you've reached that stage, no more requests are going to run.

Comment: BTW, this setting is configurable, it's `shutdownTimeout` and I believe the default is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the scope of the mess your object makes, of course.

There will be only one instance of _lock in **each AppDomain**.  If your object expects exclusive access to a resource shared between AppDomains, such as a particular file, this might be trouble.  At what level should shared access be allowed?  By different processes?  By different users?  Never?  That will help us find you a solution.

EDIT: Be afraid, be very afraid, if you're using static member variables to lock machine-global resources.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0e570911-b88e-46be-96eb-a82f737dde5a.mspx?mfr=true

Applies to IIS 7 as well

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735056(WS.10).aspx

EDIT: For an actual machine-wide lock, have a look at [System.Threading.Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf(v=VS.100).aspx)  Use either the LOCAL\ or GLOBAL\ prefix depending on whether you want one mutex per user session or computer-wide.

EDIT: Use a try/finally to make sure the Mutex gets released.

Comment: Will ASP.Net ever use multiple AppDomains on the same machine for the same application?

Comment: Did someone say same application?  I didn't hear anyone say same application.  I'm not that familiar with ASP.NET, but I think the host  recycling feature does indeed fire up a new AppDomain or new process every N requests, during which time the old process may still be finishing earlier requests.

Comment: The scope of the mess is pretty spectacular, although it's not the source of my particular problem. Picture an ODBC.INI file with tens of thousands of entries, all Oracle Lite databases with GUID names. And a corresponding entry for each in the registry. Not to mention a folder filled with hundreds of blank databases (~200K each) each time the out of memory error shows back up.

Comment: @Ben: if what you say is true, maybe that's my problem. The first request locks the object, the next 19 block waiting for the first to finish, but then the next call gets a new AppDomain and isn't locked out of using the dangerous object.

Comment: I should mention that I'm trying to achieve absolutely no shared access at all - on a particular server, I want there to only be one instantiated object of this type at a time.

Comment: I *am* very afraid - I knew I was screwing this up.

Comment: @Ben: I added the try/catch/finally, but I'm even more afraid now. There are situations where Oracle Lite crashes the thread it's running on, such that the finally block never executes. From my reading on mutex, it seems to be unclear what actually happens to a global mutex like this in that situation, i.e. whether it gets freed up or not. I'm afraid it could essentially lock out all Oracle Lite access until a reboot.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: If you end up with a total process crash, such that the `finally` block of a thread that has acquired the mutex never executes and releases it, then the global mutex goes into `WAIT_ABANDONED` state.  In .NET, any other threads waiting on that mutex will receive an `AbandonedMutexException`.

Comment: @Aaronaught: ai-yi-yi. So I need another try/catch around `mx.WaitOne();`? I assume in the catch block I would try to grab the "Global\MyMutex" mutex again?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Actually, what you'll probably need is a try-catch inside a `while` loop, and you'll definitely want to log the failure inside the `catch` (don't try to re-acquire the mutex in there - what if it fails a second time!  exceptions inside exception handlers = evil.)

Comment: @Aarotoomanyvowels: I assume you mean a while loop around a try/catch around mx.WaitOne()? Why would I want the loop? I figured the WaitOne line would block until either it gets the mutex or the AbandonedMutexException was thrown.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Yes, indeed, `WaitOne` will block until the mutex is either acquired or abandoned - but what if several threads are competing for the mutex and they all keep crashing?  You may get the `AbandonedMutexException` several times in a row. I wouldn't tell *everyone* to go to these lengths, but yours is a special case of defensive programming and what you probably want to do is keep attempting to reacquire the mutex until either you're successful or some retry limit is reached (in which case just report failure).  So maybe a `for` loop, not a `while` loop, but same idea.

Comment: That, and you may want to use the `Mutex.WaitOne(Int32)` overload which accepts a timeout, so you can report some useful apology to the client if the Mutex isn't available, and to help prevent "forced shutdown" that occurs because you were waiting on a Mutex when the shutdown request came in.

Answer (score 1):

You could run into problems where many requests are made at once and client requests start timing out as they are all waiting on the lock. You could also run into issues in a webfarm scenario where multiple servers are handling the requests and so each has its own `_lock`. I would suggest using a queue instead. If each client comes in and adds a message to some queue, then a separate service can process the messages from the queue, one at a time, and the clients will not have to wait.

Comment: This was exactly why I didn't want to use a lock here, but potential timeouts were preferable to to rebooting the server twice a day. Ironically, the lock doesn't seem to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either using a Singleton or a Factory pattern.

Comment: How about a Factory pattern that generates a Singleton?

Comment: Or even a Singleton Factory Factory. That way you could just generate a Singleton Factory whenever you need it.

Comment: That sounds perfect. I know how I could make it thread-safe now. :)